# Django - Determine model fields and create model at runtime based on CSV file header

Tags: django, postgresql, csv

I need to determine the best approach to determine the structure of my Django app models at runtime based on the structure of an uploaded CSV file, which will then be held constant once the models are created in Django.

I have come across several questions relating to dynamically creating/altering Django models at run-time. The  consensus was that this is bad practice and one should know before hand  what the fields are.

I am creating a site where a user can upload a time-series based csv file with many columns representing sensor channels. The user must then be able to select a field to plot the corresponding data of that field. The data will be approximately 1 Billion rows.

Essentially, I am seeking to code in the following steps, but information is scarce and I have never done a job like this before:

1. User  selects  a CSV (or DAT) file.
2. The app then loads only the header row in (these  files are > 4GB).
3. The header row is split by ",".
4. I use the results from 3 to  create a table for each channel (columns), with the  name of the field the same as the individual header entry for that specific channel.
5. I then load the corresponding data into the respective tables and I ahve my models for my app that will then not be changed again.

Another option I am considering is creating model with 10 fields, as I know there will never be more than 10 channels. Then reading my CSV into the table when a user loads a file,  and just having those fields empty.

Has  anyone had experience with similar applications?

Comment: IMHO if you work with dynamic stuff etc you either want to simply use postgres+JSON or go with mongoDB or a similar nosql. SQL is design assuming that you have a mostly static schema. Also: handlling billions of rows will probably require more than one machine and use *sharding* to speed up queries.

Anyway, if the users of your application should only plot the data you may consider not using a DB at all... simply store the files and parse them on demand in a streaming manner when you plot...

Comment: Hi @Bakuriu I wanted to try mongoDB but I read several posts saying that you lose the advantages of Django by using a using it. I take it you do not agree? Unfortunately, I do have to do a little bit of pre-processing on the data that I would only like to do once due to the size- this typically involved concatenation, resampling if there are any gaps due to network latency when the data was being acquired, and occasionally joining on GPS co-ordinates. The latter is why I avoided the noSQL. How does PostGres + JSON solve the dynamic aspect?

Comment: Well the dynamic aspect is that you have no schema just a column with json which can contain arbtirary objects. Easily done. However I bet the performance for your use case would be abysmal.

Comment: I see. Perhaps having the time stamp as the first field, which would always be there as it is time-series data, and then having a column for the rest of the data in JSON to allow the time field to be used as an index to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

That are allot of records, never worked with so many. For performance the fixed fields idea sounds best. If you use PostgreSQL you could look at the JSON field but don't know the impact on so many rows.

For flexible models you could use the EAV pattern but this works only for small data sets in my experience.

Comment: Thanks @Krukas I will investigate the PostgreSQL using JSON and see what the impact is with high row count. I can't imagine this hasn't been done before- An example I could think of is in IoT analytics if another sensor is added to the system.